# How to search word of format ((int)X(int)X(int)) in pandas series (anaconda 2.7)

Tags: pandas, python-2.x

How to search word of format `((int)X(int)X(int))` in pandas series (anaconda 2.7)?
For example:

> kdkksjkdjk 10x40x0jjjjj

How to extract `"10x40x0"` ?!

Comment: Could you post your code? Please show us what you tried to do.

Comment: i needed the method to extract this format ((int)X(int)X(int)) in a series pandas
for example :
i have this series :                                                                                                                 26946 156840 14496 299852 S pts/2   00:00:01 /home/techsas/techsas/bin/TSA_CSSeapath200 UDP 0 4012 techsas3.localdomain IN 0
26952 156568 14212 299580 S pts/2   00:00:00 /home/techsas/techsas/bin/TSA_CSAshtechGPS UDP 1 4012 techsas3.localdomain IN 0
26956 156568 14176 29x95x80 S pts/2

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
result = re.search('[0-9]+?x[0-9]+?x[0-9]+?', your_text).group(0)
```

Or, if you need all occurrences, use

```
result = re.findall('[0-9]+?x[0-9]+?x[0-9]+?', your_text)
```

which will give a list instead of a single string.